# HttpClient StatusDescription is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

i use the httpclient from Microsoft.Net.Http (version 2.2.22) to request some of my mvc pages.
My page returns a HttpStatusCodeResult like:

```
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(clientResponse.StatusCode, "Blub Blub");
```

With the httpclient it is not problem to call the page. But i couldn't find a way to access the statusDescription ("Blub Blub"). Is there a way to access the description? And if not, why microsoft doesn't make it accessable? By the way if i call the site from browser (Chrome) the description is shown as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use one of the methods from `HttpClient` such as `GetAsync`

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.118).aspx)

it returns an `HttpResponseMessage` object

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx).

One of the properties of that object is `ReasonPhrase` which should contain the description that you sent.

Comment: Thx, i always searched for StatusCode and was blind to look into the "quickwatch" :-).